# is saltwater bad or good for your skin?

Tags: dermatology, water, salt

After swimming into the sea, is it better take shower immediately or wait several hours?

I found [this on yahoo.anwers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080809135129AArMoxP):

> Best Answer:  Salt water can dry up the natural oils in your skin, and
>   this in turn can lead to boils and pimples. When you have been in the
>   sea, you need to wash off the salt as soon as you can, and as you so
>   rightly say, not showering fo a week is gross.

But [livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/400377-what-are-the-health-benefits-of-swimming-in-sea-water/) says:

> The magnesium in seawater may also help hydrate and improve the
>   appearance of your skin. According to a study in the February 2005
>   edition of the “International Journal of Dermatology,” bathing in a
>   magnesium-rich Dead Sea salt solution helps promote skin moisture.
>   People with atopic dry skin, or dryness on the skin’s surface,
>   submerged one forearm for 15 minutes in a bath solution containing 5
>   percent Dead Sea salt and the other forearm in regular tap water.
>   Researchers discovered that the salt solution improved skin hydration
>   and significantly reduced skin inflammation symptoms such as redness
>   and roughness when compared to tap water. Observed skin benefits were
>   attributed to the high magnesium content of the Dead Sea salt.

I think that latter is correct, but just need confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I have been swimming 3 to 5 days a week!  About 45 min each sessiob for 5 months.  Before that. The skin of my feet was like leather.  Now they are so soft that I dont recognize my own feet.  So from my experience,  livestrong is correct.
Cheers

Comment: In a salt water pool.  And I forgot to mention.

Comment: Please add some references

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's an anecdote.  Thanks for contributing Vic, your effort is appreciated!  But Q&A on Stack Exchange works differently than most sites.  Check out our rules and posting guidelines for some good tips.  Cheers!